# What happens if a UK digital passport photo is rejected?

Tags: uk, passports, uk-citizens

My situation: I've applied online for a replacement UK passport after losing my passport.

For various reasons (that mainly come down to not reading the guidelines closely enough) I'm convinced that the digital photo I used will be rejected. What happens if that's the case? Will I need to restart the entire procedure? Will it be as simple as changing my photo?

Comment: Not an official source, but this indicates you’d receive an email asking you to submit a replacement photo, with a risk of losing your money if you don’t do so by the date stated in the email https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1-i12105-k11256981-Online_passport_photo_rejected-Tripadvisor_Support.html#replies The gov.uk site https://www.gov.uk/photos-for-passports only seems to refer to rejected photos delaying an application

Comment: That's already quite reassuring, so thanks @Traveller

Comment: If you describe why you expect the photo to be refused, it will help others to decide whether their photo is satisfactory before submitting it.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I added some vague reasoning but basically it comes down to not reading the instructions closely enough. All I can say to other people is, read the instructions.

Comment: Found this: https://old.reddit.com/r/AskUK/comments/hmzp2c/how_long_will_a_passport_renewal_take_estimate_in/fx9i9nb/

Corroborates what @Traveller posted.

Comment: Did they informed you the new photo was ok? Once you uploaded the new photo, after how many days did they approve your application?

Comment: Please, do not use the answers fields to post follow up questions, that is not how this site works. That user is likely never been back and will not see your question. So go with the information that is already available or ask a new question, for which we have the 'ask question' buttons. (But that is a real new question, a copy of this one will just be closed.)

Answer (score 7):

Several non official sources ([1](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g1-i12105-k11256981-Online_passport_photo_rejected-Tripadvisor_Support.html#replies), [2](https://old.reddit.com/r/AskUK/comments/hmzp2c/how_long_will_a_passport_renewal_take_estimate_in/fx9i9nb/)) indicate that you will receive an email telling you that the photo has been rejected and the reason why, and will ask you to submit a replacement for the photo. There is a possibility you would lose your money if you don't submit by the date given, and would have to start again.

Comment: This happened to me. (I forget the problem, I think it was too dark). I got another picture, uploaded that, and it was OK.

Comment: Yes it's happened to me, and I actually had two failed submissions before they accepted on the third occasion. It's doubtless largely automated, and fairly common to get a rejection for technical reasons.